# the method ... is not defined for the Type whem trying to create a new object

Tags: java

I'm using an ArrayList to record several newly created Person objects. My problem is that when I call the constructor  to instantiate a Person object, Java won't recognize that method (the constructor). I get an error message saying `the method Person(String, int) is not defined for the Type DemoList` Why doesn't Java realize I am trying to create another object here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DemoList {
    //input from keyboard
        static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        static ArrayList<Person> array = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("To quit, press 0, to continue, press 1 \n");
        int in = 1;


        while(in !=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");
            String name = reader.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a telephone number");
            int number = reader.nextInt();
            Person newPerson = Person(name, number);
            array.add(newPerson);
            System.out.println("Press 1 to continue or 0 to quit");
            in = reader.nextInt();
        }

        //The user typed 0


        System.out.println("Who would you like to delete? ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            Person searchPerson = array.get(i);
            if(searchPerson.name == name)
            {
                array.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        PrintArray();

    }

    public static void PrintArray()
    {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        //scroll through each item in array and put it in variable i
            for(Person i : array)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
    }

}

class Person
{
    protected String name;
    protected int number;

    public Person(String name, int number)
    {
        System.out.println("Person object created! \n");
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;

    }
}
```

Comment: To make a new `Person` you should use `new Person(name number)` - the keyword `new` is important. Without it, it's not object creation but a call to a method in the current class.

Comment: Guy's answer is correct. As a side note here, you should also define `printArray()` with a lowercase `p`, so it's unmistakably a method and not a class name.

Comment: You don't even bother telling us which line has the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To create `Person` object you need to use the keyword `new` to tell the compiler to create a `Person` object (which will indirectly result in the constructor being used) , rather than trying to call the constructor directly, like a method

```
Person newPerson = new Person(name, number);
```

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

New keyword is missing in the line number **22**, while instantiating the Person class:

```
Person newPerson = new Person(name, number);
```